# Having trouble writing a proof using modules

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The Proposition: Let p be a prime with p ≡ 3 mod 4. Prove that p cannot divide both N and N + 2 for any N ∈ ℕ.

What I understand:
Knowing that p = 3 mod 4, it can be said that p = 4k + 3.
From this, we know p must equal an odd number.

There are also 2 cases: either n is even or n is odd.

case 1: if N is even, an even that is divisible by an odd (p) will always be even.

case 2: if N is odd, an odd that is divisible by an odd (p) will always be odd.

After identifying the base information I become confused as to where to go next with the proof. Hints don't seem to really help me out although very descriptive and well explained, step by step proof solutions do.

All help is much appreciated as this is something I want to be able to grasp better but I find myself constantly struggling with this topic.

Comment: Are you sure you quoted the problem correctly? You have written both $n$ and $N$ If they are the same, then If $p$ divides both $n$ and $n+2$ then it divides their difference, whihc is $2$, so $p=2$. If they are different the question makes no sense.

Comment: You were correct I had a typo in the problem, I fixed it out. Thank you for pointing that out, I should have double checked my post before posting.

Comment: It may be easier to show that if p divides N, it cannot divide N-2.

Comment: Now, what would that look like, I really need to see an example for this to make logical sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps easier and simpler: suppose $\;p\;$ divides both $\;n\;$ and $\;n+2\;$ , then there exist integers $\;r,\,s\;$ s.t.

$$\begin{cases}I&n=rp\\{}\\
II&n+2=sp\end{cases}\;\;\stackrel{\text{subtract}\; I\; \text{from}\;\; II}\implies  \;\;\;2=(s-r)p\ldots$$

Get now a contradiction...

Comment: I don't quite understand your diagram. Where are rp and sp coming from, what exactly do they represent? On top of that I don't know why we would subtract n + 2 from n.

Comment: @Zdravstvuyte94 What does "$p$ divides $n$" mean? Well, it means that we can write $\;n=rp\;$ , with $\;r\;$ a natural number....and similar with $\;n+2\;$ . The subtraction shows us that we then get a contradiction...

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, but what is with the subtracting I from II. I am not sure how subtracting the two gets you 2 = (s - r)p. Please clarify a little more, this is a very tough subject for me.

Comment: @Zdravstvuyte94 Aren't you in college level? Sorry, but I'm not sure what your level is...Just subtract equation I from equation II (left side minus left side, equals right side minus right side), and you get $\;2=(s-r)p\;$ , so $\;p\;$ divides $\;2\;$ , and the contradiction is...

Comment: OH WOW, I never noticed n was used in both equations I'm sorry haha. Yes I am in college level but clearly, my brain is not functioning right now, I thought I saw 2 different variables so I had no clue how you were subtracting the two.